# Is array in smarty returns error

Tags: php, smarty

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'SmartyCompilerException' with message 'Syntax Error in template "./templates/diet-report.tpl" on line 3 "{if is_array($dietcontent) }" - Unexpected " }"' in ...
```

I did this:

```
    {if is_array($dietcontent) }
    There is something..
    {else}
    Noope...
    {/if}
```

When i output {$dietcontent} i get "Array". But on pages where i dont get "Array" I wish to output a text.

Why am  i getting error?

I even tried in my controller (this above is in template) :

```
$data['rapportExists'] = is_array($data['dietcontent']) ? true: false;
```

and then in my template:

```
{if $rapportExists == false }
noope
{/if}
```

Still receives the same error unexpected }

Comment: Can you post the surrounding code?

Comment: There may be an error in the code above of that line. Please show us the code from line 1.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to remove the space before `}`.  Smarty will not permit whitespace before a closing brace, or after an opening brace.  I tested this in some of my own templates and could reproduce your error by placing a space before the closing brace.

```
{if is_array($dietcontent) }
-------------------------^^^

{if $rapportExists == false }
---------------------------^^^
```

Comment: @AlienWebguy Those are Smarty 2 docs.  I just tested it in Smarty 3 and it fails with the error described.

Comment: @AlienWebguy I suspect the two examples on that page which have spaces before the `}` are typos. Notice none of the other examples have spaces.

Comment: @Michael wow, did not know that the space would generate error. It worked without, thanks! accepted

Answer (score 6):

You can do it like:

```
{if $yourArray|is_array}
do something with it
{/if}
```